# How to shorten the number in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working with JSP in one of my project -

I have initialized below variable like this in the JSP-

```
<c:set var="newCount" value="0" scope="page"/>
<c:set var="totalCount" value="${gpcover.getData().size()}" scope="page"/>
```

Now after calculation on those variables - I am using it below like this in my table -

```
<td>${(newCount/ totalCount)*100}%</td>
```

But somehow the results are coming as  -

```
94.89999999999999
```

Can I shorten down this number to `94.89%` in JSP? Is it possible to do? I tried it like this -

```
<td><%    
String newCount = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("newCount");  
String totalCount = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("totalCount");    
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(newCount); 
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(totalCount);  
double num3 = (num1 / num2) * 100 ;
out.print(num3);    
%></td>
```

But it doesnt work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this page http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm

and use an example like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<p>Formatted Number (6): <fmt:formatNumber type="number" 
            minFractionDigits="3" value="${balance}" /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this and now the results I am seeing is like this `9,490.000%` which is not the actual response I was getting.. How would I get `94.89%`? Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry, my bad, type should be number not percent - oops

Comment: Cool. But how would I get extra `%` sign as well in this case?

Comment: just put a percent sign after '/>`